# Android Screen Share - surface parameter

Tags: android, screen, agora.io

I am trying to implement screen sharing on Android using Agora.io. Their sample is quite clear:

```
MediaProjectionManager projectManager = (MediaProjectionManager) mContext.getSystemService(
Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);

// Create the intent for screen capture. Call the startActivityForResult method to use the sharing function.
Intent intent = projectManager.createScreenCaptureIntent();
startActivityForResult(intent);

MediaProjection projection;
VirtualDisplay display;

// Override and implement the onActivityResult method of the Activity where you just called startActivityForResult.
@Override
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resuleData) {
    projection = projectManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, resultData);
    display = projection.createVirtualDisplay(name, width, height, dpi, flags, surface, callback, handler);
}

// The texture retrieved from the Surface will be sent by the SDK.
rtcEngine.pushExternalVideoFrame(new AgoraVideoFrame(...));

// Stop screen sharing.
projection.stop();
```

However in the **createVirtualDisplay** their is a surface parameter. I am not sure where that comes from - or more how do I get the **Surface** of the screen? Or do I instantiate a new Surface instance? Using the constructor that accepts SurfaceTexture as parameter. Or maybe implementing SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener / OnImageAvailableListener (not sure).

Surface docs:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Surface

createVirtualDisplay docs:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection#createVirtualDisplay(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.view.Surface,%20android.hardware.display.VirtualDisplay.Callback,%20android.os.Handler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're several ways that you can obtain a Surface:

1. If you are doing some video encoding, use [MediaCodec.createInputSurface()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec#createInputSurface()) as the input to the encoding module;
2. Creating the Surface using [ImageReader.getSurface()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.html#getSurface()) if you want to receive the YUV frames;
3. And if you want to do OpenGL rendering yourself, you can create a texture under the OpenGL context, and create a SurfaceTexture using that texture, and thus create your own Surface.

But note, do not use a Surface that is already attached to the view hierarchy.